# MS Graph API - there is no users/<userid>/drive/items/<itemid>/children/<childrenid>/permissions endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, onedrive, microsoft365

I can successfully get the sharing permissions for a drive like this:

**GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/drive/items/{itemid}/permissions](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buserid%7D/drive/items/%7Bitemid%7D/permissions)**

This is giving me "grantedToV2" information which includes information on who this item has been shared with:

```
        "grantedToV2": {
            "user": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.sharePointIdentity",
                "displayName": "USER NAME",
                "email": "USER EMAIL",
                "id": "USER ID"
            }
```

I can also successfully get the children of that drive item, e.g. all the images in a folder (if the item is a folder) with this request:

**GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/drive/items/{itemid}/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buserid%7D/drive/items/%7Bitemid%7D/children)**

HOWEVER, I am struggling to get the permissions for the child items - I've tried things like:

**- GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/drive/items/{itemid}/children/{childid}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buserid%7D/drive/items/%7Bitemid%7D/children/%7Bchildid%7D) with/without permissions reference because {childid} is not a selectable endpoint**

but none of it exists.

How else could I be getting the "grantedToV2" information for the child item?

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**ahahaha, found the answer - the child, of course, is also an item, so just put the child id in here where you see {itemid}
GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/drive/items/{itemid}/permissions](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buserid%7D/drive/items/%7Bitemid%7D/permissions)**